# Filtering data-foreach rendering view with option dropdown, BatmanJS

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, coffeescript, batman.js

I am just trying to manipulate the table populated by Batman JS to filter out entries with a dropdown option box.

(html view code)

```
<select data-bind="itemvalue">
  <option
    data-foreach-item="items"
    data-bind="item.key1"
    data-bind-value="item.key1"
    >
  </option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr class="key">
    <th class="label" data-bind="keys.key1"></th>
    <th class="label" data-bind="keys.key2"></th>
    <th class="label" data-bind="keys.key3"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="item" data-foreach-item="items">
    <td class="name" data-bind="item.key1"></td>
    <td class="number1" data-bind="item.key2"></td>
    <td class="number2" data-bind="item.key3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am very lost in terms how to approach this problem. My initial thought was to use the coffeescript to select the 'item' elements and declare as "display: none," so something like

```
<option ... onchange="filterView>

//and from coffeescript

filterView = (obj) ->
selectedValue = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
temp = document.getElementsByClassName("item")
for element in temp
  name = getElementsByClassName("name").innerHTML
  if name isnt selectedValue
    element.style.display == "none"
```

but I am bit stuck at this point, wondering if there is any way to handle this with the Batman filter. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `data-showif` binding to only show rows whose `item.key1` is selected.

When you select an item from the dropdown, its `key1` gets set to `itemvalue`, so you might be able to check for that:

```
<tr data-foreach-item="items" data-showif='item.key1 | equals itemvalue'>
  <td class="name" data-bind="item.key1"></td>
  <td class="number1" data-bind="item.key2"></td>
  <td class="number2" data-bind="item.key3"></td>
</tr>
```

(I my experience you have to be a little bit careful with non-strings in the DOM. They're coerced to strings when they're rendered to the `<option>`s, so if `key1` isn't a string, you might have to use a string property for filtering.)